# How to delete all the recordings from the Voice Memos app on iOS?

Tags: ios, voice-memo

I need to delete **all** the tracks from Voice Memos app in iOS, in order to free up storage on my device. Deleting tracks one at a time is not an option since I have hundreds of them.

I am using an iPod touch 4G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the app and you'll find a little symbol with 3 horizontal stripes in the right bottom corner.
You'll get a list and you can tap the memo and click "delete" right afterwards.

Or in iTunes you can select all voice memo's after you've synced them to your PC and delete them from there.

Comment: This is not the right answer.

Comment: As in which way couldn't help you this?

Comment: First part deletes items one at a time - I need to delete all. Second part deletes tracks off the PC, not off the iOS device.

Comment: Sync again and they'll be removed

Comment: @ted.strauss, did the resync do the trick?

Comment: I found another way to delete all voice memos at once in iPhone:

Answer (score 1):

I just found another easy way to keep them on your computer and get them off your iPhone!

Just go to the playlist with all your voice memos in iTunes, Select All, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> or right click and select information from contextual menu, go to options and change media type to **music** from voice memos. It will also be transferred within your finder structure to a new artist folder that's called "alan smithees iPhone 5" or whatever and will not be included in your synched voicemail anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 14.4 (the one I have today):

Tap the Edit button on top right corner and scroll through all the recording's selection circles, then after having all recordings selected tap Delete on right corner right corner.

It's not as fast as a 'delete all' option but it think it scales well enough with hundreds of recordings as you keep your finger on the bottom left corner for continuous scrolling.